# Array Index Out Of Bound/Negative Index In Ethers/Solidity

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, solidity-0.8.x

Relatively new to smart contract development. I'm writing a small app for decentralized polling with ethers.js and React. Where users can submit a poll and vote on other polls that people have created. Each poll is represented as a struct with the information such as the poll's options, the creator of the poll etc.

I've been able to implement most of the functionality of the app, however I'm struggling to implement the voting function.

The idea is that each Poll has a zeros array with a length of the amount of options. On the front end, when an option is clicked I would increment whatever index corresponds to the option ID.

However, I seem to be running into trouble when I call this vote function and I can't figure out why.

The Error I am receiving implies the index I am incrementing is out of bounds or negative:

> code: -32603, message: "Error: VM Exception while processing
> transaction: reverted with panic code 0x32 (Array accessed at an
> out-of-bounds or negative index)"

**Here is my code the contract:**

```
contract Ballot {

    struct Voter {
        bool hasVoted;
        uint vote;
    }
 
    struct Poll {
        address creator;
        bytes32 name;
        uint256 pollId;

        bytes32[] options;
        uint256 optionsLength;
        uint256[] voteCount;

        //uint256 timeCreated;
        //uint256 endTime;
    }
    
    
    mapping (address => Voter) public voters;
    Poll[] private polls;

    function getPolls() public view returns (Poll[] memory) {
        return polls;
    }

    function vote(uint pollId, uint pollOption) external {
        Voter storage sender = voters[msg.sender];
        require(!sender.hasVoted,"Already Voted");

        polls[pollId].voteCount[pollOption] +=1; //incrememnt the index of the option by one vote
        sender.hasVoted = true;
    }

    function publishPoll(bytes32 _name, bytes32[] memory _options) public {

        require(_options.length < 9,"Poll options must be smaller than nine.");
        require(_options.length > 1, "Poll options must be two or larger");

        uint arrayIndex = polls.length + 1; //get new index of poll in array, this will be the pollId
        Poll memory newPoll;

        newPoll.creator = msg.sender;
        newPoll.name = _name;
        newPoll.options = _options;
        newPoll.pollId = arrayIndex;
        newPoll.options = _options;
        newPoll.optionsLength = _options.length;
        newPoll.voteCount = new uint256[] (_options.length);

        polls.push(newPoll);
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Just reproduced the code on remix and it works fine.

What arguments are you passing from your front end when calling the vote function?

Also, this is a weird design, as the voters[msg.sender] gets mark as sender.hasVoted after voting, it mean that that address cannot vote for any other poll ever.

Comment: @OlivierD yes I figured that out last! Now I've changed the functionality of checking if a user has voted by providing a mapping of address => pollId. However, I seem to running into more problems :(